# Error after compiling when calling `this.$ons.notification.alert(...)` in Onsen, using Vue.js + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, onsen-ui

I'm trying to call `$ons` methods of Onsen UI (2.11.5) in a Vue.js (2.5.17) + TypeScript (3.0.0) application.

It works fine when calling it inside the template, but it causes an error in the command line just after `Compiled successfully` when calling `this.$ons.{method name}` inside a Vue derived class.

The error is:

```
ERROR in /Users/max/.../src/views/TestOns.vue
Property '$ons' does not exist on type 'TestOns'. Did you mean '$on'?
```

But although there's a compiler error, the code works, so both alerts (1) and (2) are popped up.

```
<template>
  <v-ons-page>
    <app-header title="About" />
    <div class="content about">

      <!-- Next tag works fine, no errors -->
      <v-ons-button @click="$ons.notification.alert('You clicked me (1)')">
        Click me! (1)
      </v-ons-button>

      <!-- Next tag will call the method that causes an error -->
      <v-ons-button @click="clickMe2()">
        Click me! (2)
      </v-ons-button>

    </div>
  </v-ons-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class TestOns extends Vue {

  private clickMe2() {
    // Next line causes a compiler ERROR, but it works nevertheless!
    this.$ons.notification.alert('You clicked me! (2)')
  }

}
</script>
```

And this is what I have in `main.ts`:

```
(...)
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueOnsen from 'vue-onsenui';
(...)
import 'onsenui/css/onsenui.css';
import 'onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css';
(...)
Vue.use(VueOnsen);
(...)
```

I came up with a workaround binding an attribute with a call to a function on the template:

```
<template>
  <v-ons-page :set-ons="setOns($ons)">
  ...
</template>

@Component
export default class TestOns extends Vue {
  ...

  private ons: any = undefined;

  public setOns(ons: any): string {
      console.log(ons);
      this.ons = ons;
      return '';
  }
...
}
```

Then you can access by `this.ons`

```
this.ons.notification.alert('You clicked me! (2)')
```

You can also pass `$ons` as a parameter in the event, for instance, `@click="clickMe($ons)"`.

But I'd like to know, why the compile error calling `this.$ons` inside the class, as told in Onsen UI documentation. And why an error if it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 satisfactory solutions:

The first one is to declare the member variable in the component. No need to init.

```
@Component
export default class TestOns extends Vue {
  ...
  private $ons: any;
  ...
}
```

The second one is to include this code anywhere in `src/main.ts`:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $ons: any;
  }
}
```

The solution described in documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins), which didn't work for me, consists on creating a file `src/types/ons.d.ts` with this content:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $ons: any;
  }
}
```

The problem is that this file seems to be ignored, although it's in the path for type definitions set in `tsconfig.json`.